# how to calculate large value of phi in central limit theorem?

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

I have $\Phi(7.5)$ in my solution how do I calculate this large value from the Z table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the values for values displayed are very close to 1 as your $z$ value gets larger (for example, $z=3.00$ gets you $\phi(3.00) = .9987$.

For a value $z = 7.5$, it is so far off the table you can essentially assume it to be 1.